# Intuition for $T - \lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the intuition behind the transformation $T - \lambda I$ where $T$ is an operator on a vector space $V$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$'s? Is there a nice way to visualise or think about it? I only know that ($T- \lambda I$)'s nullspace is the eigenspace of $T$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and ($T- \lambda I$)'s range is an invariant subspace of $V$ under $T$.

Comment: I mean, that's kinda about it. The kernel of a transformation is easier to handle than an arbitrary eigenspace, so this transformation allows us to write the eigenspace as a kernel of a transformation.

Comment: @N I think that the key thing to keep in mind is that for a vector $v \in V$,
$$
(T - \lambda I)v = 0 \iff Tv - \lambda I v = 0 \iff T v = \lambda v,
$$
but this is less an "intuitive trick" than it is the proof of the statement that the kernel of $T - \lambda I$ is the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$.